# My phonegap app was rejected after uploading it to Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, phonegap-plugins, phonegap, phonegap-cli

When I have make a APK file using buildPhonegap App and upload on Google player Store It will Give me error:

> We rejected APPNAME, with package name com.mindcrew.APPNAME, for
>   violating our Malicious Behavior policy. If you submitted an update,
>   the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.
>   This app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for
>   users. Below is the list of vulnerabilities and the corresponding APK
>   versions that were detected in your recent submission. Please upgrade
>   your app(s) as soon as possible and increment the version number of
>   the upgraded APK.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "com.mindcrew.BLM_Brisco_Pro_App"
        version   = "1.7">
    <name>BLM / Brisco Pro App</name>
    <description>
       BLM / Brisco Pro App
    </description>
    <author href="http://briscosystems.com" email="support@mindworq.com">
        BLM / Brisco Pro App
    </author>
    <content src="index.html"/>
    <access origin="*"/>
    <platform name="android">
    <!-- a preference specific to android only here -->
    </platform>
    <feature name="Device">
    <param name="android-package"value="org.apache.cordova.device.Device"/>
    </feature>
    <!-- Core/Common Preferences -->
    <preference name="Fullscreen" value="true"/> 
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/> 
    <preference name="Orientation" value="landscape"/>
    <preference name="HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar" value="false"/>
    <preference name="BackgroundColor" value="0xff0000ff"/>
    <!--iOS Preferences-->
    <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="true"/> 
    <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false"/>
    <preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="true"/>
    <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true"/>
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="false"/>
    <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="true"/>
    <preference name="GapBetweenPages" value="0"/>
    <preference name="PageLength" value="0"/>
    <preference name="PaginationBreakingMode" value="page"/>
    <preference name="PaginationMode" value="unpaginated"/>
    <preference name="UIWebViewDecelerationSpeed" value="fast"/>
    <!--Android Preferences-->
    <preference name="KeepRunning" value="false"/> 
    <preference name="LoadUrlTimeoutValue" value="10000"/>
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="mySplash"/>
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000"/>
    <preference name="InAppBrowserStorageEnabled" value="true"/>
    <preference name="LoadingDialog" value="My Title,My Message"/>
    <preference name="LoadingPageDialog" value="My Title,My Message"/>
    <preference name="ErrorUrl" value="myErrorPage.html"/>
    <preference name="ShowTitle" value="true"/>
    <preference name="LogLevel" value="VERBOSE"/>
    <preference name="SetFullscreen" value="false"/>
    <preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTop"/>
    <!--BlackBerry 10 Preferences-->
    <preference name="ChildBrowser" value="disable"/> 
    <preference name="PopupBlocker" value="enable"/>
    <preference name="WebSecurity" value="disable"/>    
    <!--<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0" />-->
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="permissions" value="none"/> 
    <access origin="*" launch-external="yes" /> 
    <access origin="geo:*" launch-external="yes" />
    <feature name="Device">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVDevice" />
    </feature>  
    <feature name="File">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils" />
    </feature>  
    <feature name="FileTransfer">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="File">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFile" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="FileTransfer">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFileTransfer" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Camera">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCamera" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Notification">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.dialogs.Notification" />
    </feature>  
    <feature name="Vibration">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.vibration.Vibration" />
    </feature>
    <!-- for Android (you will find one in res/xml) -->
    <feature name="SocialSharing">
    <param name="android-package" value="nl.xservices.plugins.SocialSharing" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Geolocation">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.geolocation.GeoBroker" />
    </feature>
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" /> 
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" source="npm" />    
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" source="npm" />    
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" source="npm" /> 
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" source="npm" />   
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" source="npm" />  
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" source="npm" />    
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" source="npm" /> 
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" source="npm" />    
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" source="npm" />   
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" source="npm" />  
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" source="npm" /> 
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" source="npm" />   
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" source="npm" /> 
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" source="npm" />  
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" source="npm" /> 
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" source="npm" />   
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" source="npm" />  
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" source="npm" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/Brisco.png" platform="android" qualifier="ldpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/Brisco_57.png" platform="android" qualifier="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/Brisco_72.png" platform="android" qualifier="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/Brisco_76.png" platform="android" qualifier="xhdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/Brisco_120.png" platform="android" qualifier="xxhdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/Brisco_152.png" platform="android" qualifier="fr-xxhdpi" /> 
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/Brisco.png" gap:platform="ios" gap:qualifier=""/>    
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/Brisco_57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/Brisco_72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/Brisco_76.png" gap:platform="ios" width="76" height="76" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/Brisco_120.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/Brisco_152.png" gap:platform="ios" width="152" height="152" />
        <!-- ios -->
</widget>
```